# Maximizing Utility

Tags: calculus, contest-math

A farmer learns that he will die at the end of the year (day 365, where today is day 0) and that he has a number of sheep. He decides that his utility is given by $ab$ where $a$ is the money he makes by selling his sheep (which always have a fixed price) and $b$ is the number of days he has left to enjoy the profit; i.e., $365-k$ where $k$ is the day. If every day his sheep breed and multiply their numbers by $\frac{103}{101}$ (yes, there are small, fractional sheep), on which day should he sell them all?

Comment: Let $s$ be the number of sheep and let $p$ be the selling price per sheep. Therefore, $s*\left(\frac{103}{101}\right)^k$ is the current number of sheep per day, where $k$ is the current day. He has $365-k$ days left to live. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I don't know how to maximize it without a calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume for simplicity that he has $1$ sheep and the price of a sheep is equal to $1$ (You can do that without loss of generality). Now, if he sells on the $k$-th day he will have utility $$U(k)=\left(\frac{103}{101}\right)^k\cdot(365-k)$$ 
So you need to maximize the function $U(k)$ with respect to $k$. Since $$\frac{\partial}{\partial k}a^k=a^k\cdot \ln a$$ you have that $$\begin{align*}\frac{\partial}{\partial k}U(k)&=\left(\frac{103}{101}\right)^k\cdot \ln\left(\frac{103}{101}\right)\cdot(365-k)-\left(\frac{103}{101}\right)^k\\&=\left(\frac{103}{101}\right)^k\cdot\left(365\cdot\ln\left(\frac{103}{101}\right)-1-k\cdot\ln\left(\frac{103}{101}\right)\right)\end{align*}$$ Setting $U'(k)=0$ you obtain that $$k=\frac{365\cdot\ln\left(\dfrac{103}{101}\right)-1}{\ln\left(\dfrac{103}{101}\right)}=314.001634$$ Hence the answer is that he will maximize his utility if he sells his sheep on the $314$-th day ($51$ days before he dies).

---

Indicative of his utility are the following examples. If he sells on day

- $k=0$ he will have utility: $$\left(\frac{103}{101}\right)^0\cdot(365-0)=365$$
- $k=1$ he will have utility: $$\left(\frac{103}{101}\right)^1\cdot(365-1)=371.2$$
- $k=2$ he will have utility: $$\left(\frac{103}{101}\right)^2\cdot(365-2)=377.5$$
- $\ldots$
- $k=313$ he will have utility: $$\left(\frac{103}{101}\right)^313\cdot(365-313)=24069$$
- $k=314$ he will have utility: $$\left(\frac{103}{101}\right)^314\cdot(365-314)=24074$$
- $k=315$ he will have utility: $$\left(\frac{103}{101}\right)^315\cdot(365-315)=24069$$
- $\ldots$
- $k=364$ he will have utility: $$\left(\frac{103}{101}\right)^364\cdot(365-364)=1258$$
- $k=365$ he will have utility: $$\left(\frac{103}{101}\right)^365\cdot(365-365)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $s$ be the number of sheep and let $p$ be the selling price per sheep.

Therefore, $s*\left(\frac{103}{101}\right)^k$ is the current number of sheep per day, where $k$ is the current day.

We can say that $a = s*p = s*p*\left(\frac{103}{101}\right)^k$ and $b = 365 - k$

Therefore, his utility can be represented as:

$$U = ab = \left(sp\left(\frac{103}{101}\right)^k\right)(365-k) = 365sp\left(\frac{103}{101}\right)^k - spk\left(\frac{103}{101}\right)^k$$

Since we are finding the day, differentiating with respect with $k$:

$$U' = 365sp\left(\frac{103}{101}\right)^k\ln\left(\frac{103}{101}\right) - sp\left(\frac{103}{101}\right)^k - 365spk\left(\frac{103}{101}\right)^k\ln\left(\frac{103}{101}\right) =0$$

$$=365sp\ln\left(\frac{103}{101}\right) - sp - 365spk\ln\left(\frac{103}{101}\right) = 0$$

$$365spk\ln\left(\frac{103}{101}\right) = 365sp\ln\left(\frac{103}{101}\right) - sp$$

$$k = \frac{365sp\ln\left(\frac{103}{101}\right) - sp}{365sp\ln\left(\frac{103}{101}\right)} = \frac{365\ln\left(\frac{103}{101}\right) - 1}{365\ln\left(\frac{103}{101}\right)} \approx 0.86$$

Comment: That seems like an unusually low number for the number of days.